# How can I make a class object callable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, instance

How can you define in Python3 a class `MyClass` such that you instantiate it like
`obj = MyClass(param1, param2)` and then use it to compute an operation like `res = obj(in1, in2, in3)` ?

For instance, with PyTorch you can declare a model as `mod = MyResNet50()` and then compute its prediction as `pred = mod(input)`.

Below is the code I tried. I declare a method and call it as `obj.method()`.

```
import numpy as np


class MLP:

    def __init__(self, hidden_units: int, input_size: int):
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.layer1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, size=(hidden_units, input_size))
        self.layer2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, size=(1, hidden_units))

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))

    def predict(self, input):
        pred = self.layer1.dot(input)
        pred = self.layer2.dot(pred)
        return self.sigmoid(pred)

my_MLP = MLP(5, 10)
pred = my_MLP.predict(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, 10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) to react to the class instance being called with `()`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    def __call__(self, in1, in2, in3):
        return f'Hello, this is {self.p1} {self.p2}. You rang? {in1} {in2} {in3}'
```

Example:

```
>>> obj = MyClass('Foo', 'Bar')
>>> res = obj(1, 2, 3)
>>> res
'Hello, this is Foo Bar. You rang? 1 2 3'
```

If your class instance does not have `__call__` defined (either itself or what it descends from) it will let you know:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    # no other methods and only descendant of `object`...
```

```
>>> MyClass('Foo', 'Bar')()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not callable
```